# Calculate the run time of a query in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can I determine in PHP how long it takes for a query to the database?

For example :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

In the above example makes a simple query, what I want is to return the time the server took to make it

Comment: @A.S.Roma Not quite, the answer in that question uses MS Specific commands and couldn't be used with PHP or MySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
// Save time
$msc = microtime(true);

// Operation
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table';
mysql_query($query);

// Calculate the difference
$msc = microtime(true) - $msc;

echo $msc . ' seconds'; // In seconds
echo ($msc*1000) . ' milliseconds'; // In millseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL command [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) to get the executiong time as in:

```
SELECT *, NOW() FROM table
```

This will return all of the rows, and the time at execution as the last, appended column.

This query will work in any programming language that can call SQL, so in PHP you would need:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, NOW() FROM table");
```

Answer (score 0):

If If you are just trying to measure the overall time taken for this query (including the MySQL Connection setup and network roundabout time), then do the following:

```
$start = microtime();
// Run Query
$end = microtime();
$qtime = ($end - $start);
```